# Infer function parameter types and spread them in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

Given a function type F, I want to create a new type that's "composable before" F, meaning it takes and returns the same arguments that F takes. For example:

```js
const stringToNumber = (s: string) => s.length;
const stringToString: ComposableOn<(s: string) => number> = (s: string) => s + s;

const composedResult = stringToNumber(stringToString('a'));
```

I've not been able to properly define the type `ComposableOn`, though. Here are things I've tried:

```js
type ComposableBefore<F extends (...args: any) => any> = (args: Parameters<F>) => Parameters<F>;
type StoN = (s: string) => number;

const sToS: ComposableBefore<StoN> = (s: string) => s + s; // error: the type is [string] => [string] and not string => string
```

```js
type ComposableBefore<F extends (...args: any) => any> = Parameters<F> extends Array<infer U>? (...args: Parameters<F>) => U: never;

const complex: ComposableBefore<(a: string, b: number, c: { d: number, e: string }) => number> = (a, b, c) => c; // not good either, since it can return a value of any type of the original function's argument types.
```

What would be a correct way to type this?

Comment: But for the multi parameter case what should the function return ?

Comment: I see now that it makes sense to return a tuple with the correct types - does this mean I would always have to wrap the return arguments in a tuple (including the single-value case), and then spread them? Like so:

`const sToS: ComposableBefore<StoN> = (s: string) => [s + s];

const sToN: StoN = (s) => s.length;

const res = sToN(...sToS('a'));
`

Comment: You could have a special case for single parameter functions .. but for multiple parameters, yes you need to return a tuple and you need to spread it. The arguments don't need to be a tuple, you can use rest on the parameters: `type ComposableBefore<F extends (...args: any) => any> = (...args: Parameters<F>) => Parameters<F>;`

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `...` to spread the `Parameters` directly in the function signature. As for the return, since you want to support multiple parameters, the return type should be a tuple and thus you will need to spread the return of your function:

```
const stringToNumber = (s: string) => s.length;
const stringToString: ComposableBefore<(s: string) => number> = (s: string) => [s + s];

const composedResult = stringToNumber(...stringToString('a'));

type ComposableBefore<F extends (...args: any) => any> = (...args: Parameters<F>) => Parameters<F>;
type StoN = (s: string) => number;
```

You could also consider adding a special case for single parameter functions, if this is the common use case:

```
const stringToNumber = (s: string) => s.length;
const stringToString: ComposableBefore<(s: string) => number> = (s: string) => s + s;

const composedResult = stringToNumber(stringToString('a'));

const multiStringToNumber = (s: string, s2: string) => s.length + s2.length;
const multiStringToString: ComposableBefore<typeof multiStringToNumber> = (s: string, s2: string) => [s + s, s2 + s2];

const multiComposedResult = multiStringToNumber(...multiStringToString('a', 'b'));

type ComposableBefore<F extends (...args: any) => any> =
    F extends (a: infer U) => any ? (...args: Parameters<F>) => U :
        (...args: Parameters<F>) => Parameters<F>;
```

Comment: That last definition of `ComposableBefore` is just what I needed to make the single-argument case nicer looking. Thanks!